# Existence of scheme quotient

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, quotient-spaces, projective-schemes

I have a morphism of schemes $X\to S$ which is very nice: flat, proper, finitely presented. I also have a finite group $G$ acting (faithfully, but not necessarily freely) on $X/S$.

1) I am quite sure that this does not suffice for the existence of a quotient $X/G$, but I am stuck on finding a counterexample.

Assume also that for every point of $S$ there is a Zariski open suset of $S$ containing $S$ and such that there exists a line bundle on $X$ which is ample on the inverse image. This *should* guarantee (am I right here?) tha there is a closed imbedding in $\text{Proj}(\mathcal{A})$ where $\mathcal{A}$  is a quasi-coherent algebra on $S$.

2) Does the quotient exist now?

(it surely exists locally on $S$).

Comment: If it can be useful, the "standard" condition that one asks in order to grant the existence of the quotient (over a field, though) is quasi -projectivity of $X$. I don't know when this condition is also necessary, but I think that, in general, it is not.